# Error while running react custom widget Azure API management developer portal in local

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to create a custom widget in Azure API management developer portal using react template. I can't run the custom widget locally and facing below error.
[image: custom widget error]

Error: utils.ts:57 Could not get 'editorData' from the search params of the URL:
http://localhost:3000/?editorData= SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

The code is failing in Microsoft libraries.

I have followed this article from Microsoft but It did not help to resolve the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-extend-custom-functionality#create-and-upload-custom-widget

Answer (score 0):

Remove  element from "main.tsx", it will unblock you.
It should look like this:

```
<StrictMode>
  <WidgetDataProvider>
    <App />
  </WidgetDataProvider>
</StrictMode>
```